# Python: Understanding the plotting syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand the plotting syntax/logic of python. So far I have always found a way around it but I think it's time to understand it.
Often I use this:

```
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
```

Then I add a subplot to that fig-object:

```
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

And then I do whatever:

```
    ax1.plot( .......... )
```

And then I save it:

```
    fig.savefig("myfile")
```

Why isn't the syntax just:

```
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
```

And then add whatever you want in the plot:

```
    fig.plot()
```

And then save it:

```
    fig.savefig()
```

Why do you create a new object ("ax1 =")? Is it because you can have multiple subplot objects within the fig object and ax1 is just a pointer to the sub-object within the object? But then what happens if you have 2 sub-objects in the fig object and say savefig? Which sub-object is then saved?

Last but not least: Why does my current code not work?

```
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.bar(range(3822), a_vals, color = 'r')
    fig.savefig("plot_file")
```

In the result the barplot is not red, it's black?

Answer (score 4):

You have several questions here. The last one, in particular, should have been better posted separately.

> Why do you create a new object ("ax1 =")? Is it because you can have multiple subplot objects within the fig object and ax1 is just a pointer to the sub-object within the object?

Yes, it is correct.

> But then what happens if you have 2 sub-objects in the fig object and say savefig? Which sub-object is then saved?

The whole figure gets saved. You may want to have several plots in the same figure, either side by side

[image: plot grid]

(http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html)

or, maybe, one plot as an inset in a bigger one

[image: insets]

(http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html)

In any case, a `figure` is the canvas you draw on, and it is the thing that gets saved. You may argue that it would be convenient to provide a shortcut for the default case of one plot per figure, but as far as I know it only exists in the "matlab"-style stateful interface, not in the Python-style OO interface that you are using.

> Last but not least: Why does my current code not work?

`bar()` has two color settings: border color (keyword `edgecolor`) and fill color (keyword `color`). The default for the former one is black. Since you have a lot of bars and non-zero edge thickness, all you see are edges, which are black (you can test it by reducing the number of bars from `3822` to several dozen).

Therefore you have two ways:

1. Set `edgecolor` to whatever you want it to:

   ```
   ax1.bar(range(3822), a_vals, color = 'r', edgecolor='r')
   ```
2. Or, better, don't draw the edges at all and use the fill color:

   ```
   ax1.bar(range(3822), a_vals, color = 'r', linewidth=0)
   ```

Example:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot

a_vals = numpy.random.normal(size=3822)

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.bar(range(3822), a_vals, color = 'r', linewidth=0)
fig.savefig("plot_file")
```

[image]